# Can't download and install extension

Tags: extension

On a fresh 5.47.3 on WP 5.9.2 on CentOS / Plesk I can't download and install extensions from the extension manager

Error message: `Extension Download failed - ZIP file is unavailable or malformed`

Of course I can install with FTP client but I'd prefer to install the regular way

EDIT 1: this happens only for some extensions

Comment: is it that same message for any extension you try?

Comment: yes and actually we encounter this on different instances on the same server. So I guess it's related to our configuration :-(